# How to encode lua class to json?

Tags: json, lua

I have LUA class:

```lua
local mod = {}
Person = {}
function Person:new()
    local obj = {}
    obj.name = nil

    function obj:setName(name) self.name = name end
    setmetatable(obj, self)
    self.__index = self;
    return obj
end
mod.Person = Person
return mod
```

and I need to serizalize instance of class to json.
But when I use `cjson.encode(classes.Person:new())`, I get error: `: Cannot serialise function: type not supported
stack traceback:`

Comment: Function obj:setName() should be moved to the class.  `function Person:setName(name) self.name = name end`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff that's right. You can submit answer.